# How to deploy a mini-site?

Tags: reactjs, deployment

I'm not really sure the if the question fits but I'm going with it.

I'm building a project that I have invested quite some time in. I'm at the point where I need the user to be able to "deploy" or even share their creation with someone else... ( It is a React app )

Let's say the user has an account and has created a kind of geocache treasure hunt.
He/she has provided 5 different clues to the locations of caches that he/she has hidden around their city. And maybe there is a field to enter a password or a button when the end-user finds the cache.

Now, the user needs to deploy this geo quest.
Not exactly share it... I don't want the end-user to have to access the original user's account/content. It needs to all be contained in a kind of mini-site.

What would be the best way to accomplish this?

Let me know if I need to clarify anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Do you already have a back-end setup to accomplish the register/login process ?
If not you could use a Headless-CMS such as [Strapi](https://strapi.io/). Strapi is quite simple to use and offers a user management preset.

Comment: I do. Using Firebase & Firestore right now for development.